# Sql Parameters already been declared

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So i'm trying to use parameters in SQL as in my database someone has a surname of "O'Brien" as you can imagine without using parameters this caused me a lot of hell, before you start screaming at me telling me i should have already been using paramaterised queries, i'm very new to using SQL properly and haven't had the time to learn how to do it properly yet so I've just been using string queries for the time being so, my code is as follows:

```
//string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EBSLIVE"].ConnectionString;
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EBSTEST"].ConnectionString;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        foreach (string name in StringNames)
        {
            string[] StuName = name.Split('|');
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER as Number From people Where FORENAME = @FORENAME and SURNAME = @SURNAME and PERSON_CODE = @PERSONCODE";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PERSONCODE", StuName[0]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORENAME", StuName[1]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SURNAME", StuName[2]);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(ndt);
                    dt.Merge(ndt);
                }
            }
        }
    }              
}
Numbers.AddRange(dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("Number")).ToList());
```

But for some reason it tells me that @PERSONCODE has already been declared. I have no clue of whats going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Move the parameter statements underneath the commandtext statement

Comment: i suspect you should switch the order of the `using` and the `foreach`-loop, so wrap the using inside the foreach loop and you're good to go

Comment: Still not working after i did that

Comment: @ReeceHewitson who are you referring to?

Comment: you can get round the O'Brien problem with Surname = Surname.Replace(@"'", @"''") - if you need a quick workaround in c# - just make any ' in a literal into two occurrences of ' together - that's how to escape ' in SQL literals

Comment: @nozzleman i was refering to Bugfinder

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s seems to me its just less efficient but it's easier to write and im in a situation where i dont need to worry about performance so does it really matter if i use `.AddWithValue()` or `.Add()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same `SqlCommand` for different `DataAdapters`, but you are creating and adding the parameters in the loop, so the `SqlCommand` gets multiple parameters with identical names. That's not allowed of course.

You don't need the `SqlCommand` but you can reuse `DataAdapter.SelectCommand` every time. I wouldn't use `AddWithValue`:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER as Number From people Where FORENAME = @FORENAME and SURNAME = @SURNAME and PERSON_CODE = @PERSONCODE", con))
{
    var cmd = da.SelectCommand;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PERSONCODE", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FORENAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SURNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

    foreach (string name in StringNames)
    {
        string[] StuName = name.Split('|');
        cmd.Parameters["@PERSONCODE"].Value = StuName[0];
        cmd.Parameters["@FORENAME"].Value = StuName[1];
        cmd.Parameters["@SURNAME"].Value = StuName[2];

         DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(ndt);
         dt.Merge(ndt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense now,  thanks i appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (string name in StringNames)
{
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
        string[] StuName = name.Split('|');
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PERSONCODE", StuName[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORENAME", StuName[1]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SURNAME", StuName[2]);
        cmd.CommandText = "Select MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER as Number From people Where FORENAME = @FORENAME and SURNAME = @SURNAME and PERSON_CODE = @PERSONCODE";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //your other stuff and merging to the main dt.
   }
}
```

You should put declaration of `SqlCommand` inside the `foreach` loop. On every iteration you are defining the parameters again which leads to this error.

**EDIT:** If you want to reuse the same command just call in the begging of the loop:

```
foreach (string name in StringNames)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    //other stuff.
}
```

Comment: Okay, so i need to use a new command every time? i cant just re-define the parameters?

Comment: Other possibility is to call cmd.Parameters.Clear() in the begging of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the command outside the loop, then you add the parameters inside the loop. Of course then the parameter is already there.

I second your approach of using the same command throughout all the loops to avoid having to re-create it, but then you have to re-structure your code:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER as Number From people Where FORENAME = @FORENAME and SURNAME = @SURNAME and PERSON_CODE = @PERSONCODE";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PERSONCODE", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FORENAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SURNAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    foreach (string name in StringNames)
    {
        string[] StuName = name.Split('|');

        cmd.Parameters["@PERSONCODE"].Value = StuName[0]);
        cmd.Parameters["@FORENAME"].Value = StuName[1]);
        cmd.Parameters["@SURNAME"].Value = StuName[2]);

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(ndt);
                dt.Merge(ndt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can even declare the data adapter outside the loop as Tim says in his answer.